# How to get parameter of current selected SELECT?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select id="sel">
    <option value="1" test="aaa">dsfsdf</option>
    <option value="2" test="bbb">ssssss</option>
    <option value="3" test="ccc">dggggg</option>
</select>

<span id="check">check</span>

$("#check").click(function(){

console.log($("#sel option").attr("selected", true).attr('test'));
})
```

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/rhqbG/

Now this show me always "aaa". How can i make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could rewrite it to

```
console.log($("#sel option:selected").attr('test'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gYpYV/

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('sel').value;
```

Should do the trick.

**EDIT**

```
var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
// now get attributes of opt, such as:
console.log(opt.getAttribute("test"));
```

Comment: i want get attribute test, not value

Answer (score 1):

Just to note, it's poor practice to include non-conforming custom attributes on elements. If you're using HTML 5 you can use "data-" custom attributes, but otherwise it would be preferable to maintain a JavaScript hash of values associated with the element.